# How max function works on dictionary in python?

Tags: python, dictionary, max

If my dictionary is: `dict_1 = {'a':6,'b':4,'c':3}`

`max(dict_1)`
will return me
`'c'`
How does this work?

I think is it `max(dict_1)` will return maximum(c> a&b if we write this in letters i.e. a=1,b=2,c=3) of keys, is it right?

And if it is right so how `max(dict_1,key=dict_1.get)` will return me `6` it should have returned `3` considering above statement right ?
any leads? TIA.

Comment: What did you find when you looked up the `get()` method of `dict`?

Comment: If you use a dictionary as an iterator, you will iterate over the keys, not the values.

Comment: When you just `max` a `dict`, `max` will evaluate the keys to find max. In case of strings, python uses `ord`, where `ord("c")` is 99 and the greates (check `[ord(i) for i in "abc"]`)t.

Comment: @all... here in max should iterate over keys and should return max key in  max(dict_1,key=dict_1.get)

Comment: Well, it doesn't. What ever makes you think that it should?

Comment: Now you’ve changed your question. The .get just looks at the values and ignores the keys.

Comment: @quamrana to ask properly what i m trying to ask here i have updated the question... my question here is there are two elements in `max(dict_1,key=dict_1.get)` i.e `dict_1` and `key=dict_1.get` i want to know on which part `max()` function is operating? `dict_1` or `key = dict_1.get` ? as per my understanding(let me know if i am wrong) `max()` function should run over `dict_1` and should return 'c' and in that case i am not getting use of `key=dict_1.get` ?

Comment: also `max(dict_1.values(),key=dict_1.get)` this code returns ans as `b` which seems correct as `max()` runs over dict_1.values() and `key=dict_1.get` returns key for that max value. but want to know how `max(dict_1,key=dict_1.get)` this works...... TIA

Comment: `max(dict_1)` returns `'c'` because `ord('c')` is the largest key. `max(dict_1, key=dict_1.get)` returns `'a'` because `6` is the largest value. It picks `6` because as `max` iterates over `dict_1` it just sees the keys, but passes the keys to `dict1.get()` an that gets the corresponding value. `max(dict_1.values(),key=dict_1.get)` throws a `TypeError` since none of the `values()` are keys, so `dict_1.get()` returns `None`.

Comment: The `max()` function iterates over the first argument. When you supply `dict_1`, you are supplying `dict_1.keys()`. When you also supply `key=dict_1.get`, `max` uses the function supplied to transform each key when it performs compares. Without the `key` argument, it compares keys for their values alone (ie `ord()` in your case). With the `key` argument you can make `max` substitute different values for the comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Actually function max() will return the highest index.
Like if you example

```
dict = {'a':6, 'b':4, 'c':9}
```

will return the 'c' letter - which is the biggest key.
You can also manipulate this with other functions like:

```
max(dict.values())
```

will return you the biggest value of whole dictionary.

Comment: The OP already confirmed that `max(dict_1)` returns `'c'`. But *why* does this happen?